# How to return the array attribute from DB using SPI function

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions

I have a table test with an attribute that is an array of the array of string.

For example the array "ar" is
`{{1,A},{A,B,C},{45}}`

Now I want to check if there is  a value between the array.
For example if `{A,B,C}` is member of the array "ar".

I'm working inside the core of postgres (postgres.c), so I'm using the SPI function.

```
SPI_connect();
SPI_exec("select * from test", 0);
if (SPI_processed > 0){
    char *s=SPI_getvalue(SPI_tuptable->vals[SPI_processed],SPI_tuptable->tupdesc,1);
}
```

but SPI_getvalue returns a string and I need the array in order to check the if the array is a member of the main array "ar".

Is there any SPI function that does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not any SPI function, that returns info about arrays. SPI functions are usually type agnostics - list of SPI functions http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi.html

You should to use a SPI_getbinval - it returns a binary (Datum) value

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi-spi-getbinval.html

Next, you can analyze a postgresql/src/backend/utils/adt/array*.c files, if there is some useful function that helps to you. There is a static array_contain_compare and mainly a arrayoverlap, arraycontains and arraycontained. You can call these functions via DirectFunctionCall API - see this nice Greg's tutorial http://www.pgcon.org/2010/schedule/attachments/142_HackingWithUDFs.pdf or you can do it on SQL level, and then result will be a boolean - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

```
postgres=# select '{{1,A, 1},{A,B,C},{45,46,47}}'::text[] @> '{A,B,C}';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Processing on SQL level is usually much more simpler than using DirectFunctionCall API.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working with SPI_getbinval but I was not able to get progress. I'm going to do the query like you suggested me, but with the SPI and after check the result if is `T` or `F`.